# Rare error when trying to save data "unhandled exception on the current circuit"

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor

I am using VS 2022, Blazor server project. When I trying to save data

```
    async public static Task<bool> updateObject(Firecall obj)
    {
        Firecall r;
        try
        {
            using (var context = new sptContext())
            {
                r = context.Firecalls.Where(c => c.Mguid == obj.Mguid).FirstOrDefault();
                bool новое = (r == null);
                if (новое)
                {
                    r = new Firecall();
                }
                r.comment = obj.comment;

                if (новое)
                    await context.Firecalls.AddAsync(r);

                if (busy)
                    return false;
                try
                {
                    busy = true;
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    return false;
                }
                finally {
                    busy = false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

sometimes I get error:
[image: Error when try to save]

Sometimes an error occurs, sometimes not. No error in debugger.
How to solve problem?

P.S. Data in each operation is saved as expected. Only after the operation is completed the indicated error message appear
And calling savechanges method from @code block of .razor view:

```
async private void SaveChanges()
{
  bool rez = await firecallRepository.updateObject(_currentFireCall);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to enable 'details exceptions' like it suggests?

Comment: {
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}

Comment: can you include the @code block for the blazor/razor view calling this method? (is the call is awaited?) The "busy" flag setting prior to SaveChanges seems a bit late. I'm guessing this is to try and avoid concurrency issues between requests so checks will be limited to 1 read/write at a time. This isn't a good approach from a scalability perspective as *ALL* inserts/updates will be bottlenecked rather than handling the exception where a duplicate row might be attempted due to a race condition.

Comment: Included the @code block for the blazor/razor view calling saveChanges method

Comment: Done, problem remains

Comment: After re-publishing, the error may disappear for a while, but then it starts to appear again with each save operation.